# Does Plaid transactions call bring back transactions for all connected accounts? or just 1 account?

Tags: plaid

Im setting up a Finance app and need to know if the plaid API brings back all transactions for all connected accounts or just the one I am looking at with the access token?

I have tried to loop through to connect the accounts but all of them return the same data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plaid access tokens work institution wise, unless you enabled the option of account selection in linking process. If you had done so, for example, if the user selected Bank A , and then selected saving account while also having a checking account, you will get only saving account information. Otherwise, you should be able to load all accounts information from the same bank. Some limitations apply as for example credit accounts from a specific bank may not be available to Plaid , then you will have no access to such accounts in both cases.